# how to add external package to flutter with visual studio code

Tags: flutter

the doc reference android studio, but I'm using Visual Studio Code, so how do I do this?

"While viewing the pubspec in Android Studio’s editor view, click Packages get upper right."

in pubspec.yaml I added "english_words: ^3.1.0", and I ran 'flutter packages get' from the command palette but it's not working.

Comment: any error msg ?

Comment: "It's not working" is not actually useful information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make sure you are saving the file before running flutter packages get

Comment: my mistake was not first saving the pubspec file, after which 'flutter packages get' ran automagically

Answer (score 2):

**HOW TO ADD EXTERNAL PACKAGE TO DART AND FLUTTER WITH VISUAL STUDIO CODE**

The final solution to this problem is here

- you will get the latest version of whatever package you are looking for
- Forget going to the pub.dev to search for your packages and copy the dependency
  text.

THE SOLUTION IS:

1. Install the "pubspec assist" by Jeroen Meijer in the extension menu.
2. Open the pubspec.yaml file in the vs code.
3. Simply open the Command Palette (by default, Ctrl+Shift+P on Windows, ⌘+Shift+P
   on Mac) and search for "Pubspec Assist" and press ENTER.
4. Then search for the required package with their names. It will automatically add
   the dependencies to the pubspec.yaml file. After that save the file using
   Ctrl+S.
5. Get ready to import the package in the main file.

Answer (score 0):

I was having error on mine too. This was my initial code

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
    http: ^0.12.2
```

and I got this error

"Error on line 25, column 5 of pubspec.yaml: A dependency may only have one source."

so I adjusted my indentation like so

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http: ^0.12.2
```

And it worked just fined